# dynamic css file for admin / backend and get_option results in Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_option()

Tags: css, wpdb, admin-css

I try to style the admin area with a dynamic css. I need to configure some elements regarding the frontend user defines. He can choose a color and this color should reflected in some elements in the admin area (e.g. buttons in admin area).
My approach: Setting up a evacolor.css, but let apache interpret this as a php file. This works so fare:

.htaccess in the same dir, as my color.css:

```
<FilesMatch "\.css$">
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
    Header set Content-type "text/css"
</FilesMatch>
```

My evacolor.css looks like:

```
<?php
 $absolute_path = explode('wp-content', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']);
 $wp_load = $absolute_path[0] . 'wp-load.php';
  header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
  header('Cache-control: must-revalidate');

    $test = "#ff00ff";
?>
 
body {
  background: <?php echo $test;?>;
}
.... and so on
```

This works fine. Now I need to pull my color out from the wp_options table and all the problems starts.

1. I tried `$color_items = get_option( 'cornerstone_color_items' );`
   => Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function get_option()
   I tried to include `include_once('wp-includes\option.php');` But this ends in
   => Call to undefined function wp_installing()
   Ok, let's includ this also `include_once('wp-includes\load.php');`
   => Call to undefined function apply_filters()

Hence.
Next try:

```
global $wpdb;    
$result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wpeva_options WHERE option_name = 'cornerstone_color_items'");
print_r($result)
```

=> Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_results()

I include `require_once($wp_load);`
=> Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.

I give up. No more ideas.

Does anyone has an idea, how to use a dynamic css (for admin, resp. backend) and use inside this css a color value, which is stored in wp_option table?
Even my attempt to define a global variable has had no success: `$GLOBALS['color'] = '#ff00ff';` and also `define('CICOLOR', '#ff00ff')`; are empty in my dynamic css;

Any ideas?
Any help?
Thank you :)

Comment: This seems like overkill. You'd have a much easier time just using CSS variables in the CSS file and defining those variables in an inline style block added by the plugin.

Comment: Thank you Jacob. But how to do this? I have a color value stored in my wp-table. This value can change. Now I need this value in my color.css from an admin color scheme. I don't know.... how can I setup this with css-variable. Any more advice? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @Jacob for pointing me in the right direction.
This was an overkill!

=> in function php I call my values, set this in a global css variable.
Pick this variable in my admin css.

Again: Thank you! Lifesaver :))